# Use Chrome portable to open a index.html file on the same USB stick for a homepage

Tags: file, google-chrome, settings, internal

IS it at all possible to set the Google homepage to a file located on my USB pen drive?

I can link it though the file path, problem being the drive letter would change depending on the system it is plugged into so a hard coded homepage link wont work.

Im unsure of the syntax to use to make it upen the file -

%USBDRIVE%/Webfiles/index.html

The page is used to help new users navigate the USB pen and get the info/files they require as its aimed as users with next to no IT skills or disabilities

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably found a solution already, but just come across your question and I recently had the same scenario. I'm assuming you mean on PC.

I solved it as follows:

In the PortableGoogleChrome folder (after portable chrome is setup on the usb drive), there is a default file called parameter.txt. I added the following in order to set the homepage to my local file. It is in a sub folder called 'resources' located on the usb drive root:

```
--homepage="\resources\index.html"
```

That's all for the parameter.txt file. That takes care of the homepage setting.

Now to launch portable chrome, I created a windows batch file called launcher.bat also at the root of the usb drive (call it whatever you like obviously!). I added the following code:

```
@echo off
cd PortableGoogleChrome
"ChromeLoader.exe"
```

The launcher file changes the directory to PortableGoogleChrome and then loads Chrome via ChromeLoader.exe which takes in your homepage or other [parameters](http://www.ericdlarson.com/misc/chrome_command_line_flags.html) in Parameters.txt.

FINALLY, in order to create an application to replace the Launcher.bat file (as I figured a windows application with icon would be more intuitive to run than the batch file), I found a windows utility called [bat_to_exe_converter](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000435.htm) which enabled me to convert the bat to an exe and supply an icon also (having tried to do so in C++, C# but errors because of needing supporting DLL's, this was much more straightforward).

Hope that's of use!

Comment: This seems perfect, but I cant find Parameter.txt. Best I can see is adding additional switches in GoogleChromePortable.ini . Am i barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Not sure about the ini file off hand - but on second thoughts I think you actually need to actually create 'parameter.txt' (sorry I misled before) in the PortableGoogleChrome folder which also contains ChromeLoader.exe.

Comment: This is such an old post, but was perfect for my needs. However, it's getting flagged as a virus in Norton and McAfee. Any thoughts?